# Windows Phone Maps: Layer from GeoServer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, maps, windows-phone-8.1, geoserver

What would be the easiest way to draw a map layer from GeoServer on Windows Phone?

From GeoServer's output formats (GeoJSON, KML, GeoRSS, Shapefile, CSV...) which do you think is more easily manipulated and converted into a Windows Phone's Map Layer's element such as a polygon?

What APIs or tutorials do you recommend about these subject?

Comment: did you ever find any solution that you would like to share with? thanks

Comment: Yes, I will post the details later..

Comment: that would be very welcome. thanks upfront

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've opted for the GeoJSON format:

```
string _buldingUrl = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Utad/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Utad:build&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json";
```

That string is the standard output when we select the layer as GeoJSON. We need to pay attention to the `&maxFeatures=50` parameters and set it for the for the value that we need.

Then I've the method that handles the Json result, and uses the map control as parameter.

```
async public void DrawRoomsonMap(Map Mapa)
        {
           ... //Response Reading

            //used the: https://github.com/GeoJSON-Net/GeoJSON.Net
            var reader = new GeoJsonReader();

            //read the json map features to a list with the help of GeoJsnoReader
            var features2 = (Geo.IO.GeoJson.FeatureCollection)reader.Read(jsonText);
            var list = features2.Features.ToList();

            //clear map elements
            Mapa.MapElements.Clear();

            //my own implementation for getting elements with a specific property, in this case a lever of some value 
            foreach (var item in list.Where(x=> x.Properties["level"].ToString() == _currentLevel.ToString()))
            {
                //converted the geometry property of each item to a Wkt string, and extracted the polygons to and array
                var b = item.Geometry.ToWktString();
                b = b.Replace("MULTIPOLYGON", "").Replace("(((", "").Replace(")))", "").TrimStart(' ');
                var c = b.Split(',');

                //Created a MapPolygon object and GeoCoordinates collection
                MapPolygon polygon = new MapPolygon();
                GeoCoordinateCollection coordenadas = new GeoCoordinateCollection();

                //added the coordinates to the polygon
                foreach (var coor in c)
                {
                    var x = coor.TrimStart(' ');
                    var lat = x.Split(' ')[0].Replace(".",",");
                    var lon = x.Split(' ')[1].Replace(".", ",");

                    double latitude = double.Parse(lat);
                    double longitude = double.Parse(lon);

                    coordenadas.Add(new GeoCoordinate(longitude, latitude));
                }

                //polygon properties and added to the map control.
                polygon.Path = coordenadas;
                polygon.FillColor = fixColor(item.Properties["bpart"].ToString());
                polygon.StrokeColor = Colors.White;
                polygon.StrokeThickness = 3;                
                Mapa.MapElements.Add(polygon);
            }
        }
```

The process for points and lines is easy to go on from this.

Comment: haven't noticed the c# tag here but this is useful as well. thank you.